# Route Table Multiple Subnet Entries?

Tags: routing, subnet, route, ifconfig

So just as a bit of context, this is for a VM running that does call processing. So I was looking at the route table on the VM, and noticed that it has this:

```
  12.12.12.64/28 dev bond15 proto kernel scope link src 12.12.12.12
  12.12.12.64/28 dev bond19 proto kernel scope link src 12.12.12.12
  12.12.12.64/28 dev bond11 proto kernel scope link src 12.12.12.12
  12.12.12.64/28 dev bond8 proto kernel scope link src 12.12.12.12
```

So my question is, does this make sense? I didn't add them to the routing table on my own these were set when the IP's were configured. But my question is, how does this work then? If a packet destined to anything on 12.12.12.64/28 comes in it's always going to go to the bond15 interface correct? Wouldn't this completely negate the bond19 and bond11 interfaces?

Now that being said, I also did an ifconfig of the VM, and noticed that all of these BOND interfaces, have the same IP:

```
  bond8: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1472
          inet 12.12.12.12  netmask 255.255.255.240  destination 12.12.12.12
 bond11: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>         mtu 1472
          inet 12.12.12.12  netmask 255.255.255.240  destination 12.12.12.12
        bond15: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1472
    inet 12.12.12.12  netmask 255.255.255.240    destination 12.12.12.12
  bond19: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1472
    inet 12.12.12.12  netmask 255.255.255.240  destination 12.12.12.12
```

So given these two pieces of information, I'm curious as to how to pull this all together. Does this mean that all of these BOND's are just using the same interface? If so why does there need to be multiple lines in the route table? and why not just have one single entry in the ifconfig that consolidates all 4 Bonds into one? So there's just one Bond0 for 12.12.12.12 and on ipconfig entry for Bond0 for 12.12.12.12 ?

The way it reads to me is that according to the route table, it any packet destined for this subnet will only go to Bond15 because it appears first in the route list?

Thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

First you should know that for any advanced network settings, `ifconfig` and `route` should be entirely avoided, and [`ip link`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-link.8), [`ip address`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-address.8), [`ip route`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-route.8) (as well as [`ip rule`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-rule.8) for policy routing, [`bridge`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/bridge.8) in addition to `ip link` to replace `brctl`) used instead. Some features are not available with older tools because newer features are implemented only in the newer kernel API ([(rt)netlink](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/rtnetlink.7) instead of ioctl).

These routes are tagged `proto kernel`: that means they were automatically added by the kernel when adding addresses to the interfaces, probably with something like:

```
ip address add 12.12.12.12 peer 12.12.12.64/28 dev bond8
```

As is alone it doesn't make much sense: only the first listed route among equals would be used: `bond15`, there has to be other elements for a correct routing.

I can think of at least two ways this is done:

- additional routing tables

  This would probably have to be working along with *conntrack zones* (to avoid mixing two identical flows except their interface), *connmarks* and *marks* (using *iptables* or *nftables*) to mark packets to know the route they came from and allowing the kernel to reply back there. The `ip rule` command returns this on a standard system:

  ```
  0:  from all lookup local
  32766:  from all lookup main
  32767:  from all lookup default
  ```

  If you have additional entries, that's probably the method chosen, and it could become quite complex if additional settings are done using *iptables* or *nftables*. For each additional entry with `lookup XXXX`, you can display the additional routing table with:

  ```
  ip route show table XXXX
  ```

  which will probably have only one *bondXX* device referenced inside it (maybe along other interfaces).
- binding directly to an interface

  Using [`SO_BINDTODEVICE`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/socket.7#Socket_options):

  > `SO_BINDTODEVICE`
  >
  > Bind this socket to a particular device like “eth0”, as specified in
  >   the passed interface name. [...] If a socket is bound to an interface,
  >   only packets received from that particular interface are processed by
  >   the socket. Note that this works only for some socket types,
  >   particularly AF_INET sockets.

  This would usually require to leave [Reverse Path Forwarding](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=linux-5.4.y#n1225) filter off for example with:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0

  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.bond8.rp_filter=0
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.bond11.rp_filter=0
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.bond15.rp_filter=0
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.bond19.rp_filter=0
  ```

  actually probably simply with this before creation of the interfaces:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
  ```

  I could get this working using [`socat`](https://manpages.debian.org/socat/socat.1) and its `so-bindtodevice=` option, but only as client (connecting), not as server (listening) so I don't know if it's for all cases, or if that was a limitation with `socat` or something I missed. Something like:

  ```
  socat tcp4:12.12.12.65:5555,so-bindtodevice=bond11 -
  ```

  to communicate with the service on port 5555/tcp on the system owning 12.12.12.65 on the *bond11* side (rather than the one on the *bond15* side).

Also despite their name, these interfaces don't appear to be of type *bond*, but probably some kind of tunnel. Using `ip -details link show` would display their actual type (at the start of the 3rd line for each interface).

Comment: First off thank you for this huge response.So yea I know that the ip xxxx command suite is what's really preferred. Old habits die hard! Anyway, I looked into this further with some of the commands you provided and wow,..the rabbit hole goes deeper..using ip --details link shows the bond interfaces, but they don't have the IP's of the 12.12.12.'s but rather just 169.x.x.x internal addresses.  but they are gre point to point links..I don't have enough space here to continue with this, I unfortunately am far more confused actually lol But thanks for your help my friend, a great jumping off point

Comment: But did you try `ip rule` as suggested in the answer?